# Can each closed, orientable 3-manifold be obtained by the double of a 3-submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

Can each closed, orientable 3-manifold be obtained by the double of a 3-submanifold of Euclidean 3-space?
(the double of $M$ is obtained by gluing two copies of $M$ together along their common boundary)

For example, $S^3$ is the double of $D^3 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, and $S^2 \times S^1$ is the double of the tubular neighborhood of $S^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and $T^3$ is the double of the tubular neighborhood of $T^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I ask this question because, for 2-manifold, it is true. Each closed, orientable 2-manifold can be obtained in a similar way. A genus g surface (g-torus) is the double of $D^2$ removed g many disks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: Orientable surface have positive genus. Is there any restriction on your "double", isomorphic according to metric or simply homotopy equivalent? In the second case, I believe so.

Comment: Not every closed connected orientable 3-manifold is a double of anything, since there are manifolds which do not admit any symmetries.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks a lot. And I have just learnt that $L(p, q), |p| > 1$, does not embed in $\mathbb{R}^4$. If it is the double of a submanifold, it could be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$. It is wrong.

Comment: Good. Now, you can write an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the helps.

The answer is negative.

The lens space $L(p, q), |p| > 1$, does not embed in $S^4$ (a manifold of dim < n embeds in $\mathbb{R}^n$ if and only if it embeds in $S^n$)

Refer from Ahmad Issa, *Embedding 3-manifolds in $S^4$*, page 4, https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/aissa/slides/candidacy.pdf.

If it is the double of a 3-submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$, it could be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$. The contradiction shows the answer is negative.

Comment: In this situation, one says "the answer is negative", not "wrong." You should also add a reference to that fact about lens spaces.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you, I have edited the answer.